# Strings from some library modules not included in application's R class

Tags: android

I have an Android app where application module depends on a few library modules.
Each of the library modules have: -

1. Different package names defined in their `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. strings defined in their `res/values/strings.xml`

Application module has a different package name defined in its `AndroidManifest.xml`

I am trying to access the strings from the library modules in my application module via

```
textView.setText(R.string.stringLibA);
textView1.setText(R.string.stringLibB);
```

However, I am getting compilation error when accessing `R.string.stringLibB` saying

`cannot find symbol R.string.stringLibB`

But it works fine if I access `stringLibB` using library's package name

```
textView.setText(R.string.stringLibA);
textView1.setText(com.package.libraryB.R.string.stringLibB);
```

Can someone please guide me what am I doing here that I cannot access `libraryB`'s strings from application module's R class directly?

I apologize I could not share actual code from the project because of privacy concerns.

**EDIT**
My application module's `build.gradle`'s dependency block

```
dependencies {
  implementation project('libraryA')
  implementation project('libraryB')
}
```

`libraryA` and `libraryB` are applying library plugin in their `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

I am trying to access strings declared in `libraryA` and `libraryB` inside of my application via application's R class

Answer (score 0):

Check your `dependency` first, make sure all of your `modules` are declared properly. If you implement `module` properly then you should have access to the modules `component` including `resources`.

Sometimes, IDE errors happen. Simply, `Invalidate & Restart` will solve your problems.

Comment: What do you mean by modules are declared properly. What things should I be looking for?

Comment: Take a look at your app level `build.gradle` files `dependency` section, make sure all 3rd party `module/lib` are defined.

Comment: These are not 3rd party libs. These are library modules I created in my project. Please see my updated question with more details